# GraphQL: Unknow directive include

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-tools

I am practicing using directives with Graphql in Nodejs. When in the Playground I want to use the @include directive, the Graphql client tells me: "Unknow directive include". This is my code:

```php
query getChar($id: ID!, $withGames: Boolean!) {
  getCharacter(_id: $id) {
    _id
    name
    race
    games @include(if: $withGames) {
      _id
      title
    }
    image
  }
}
```

In my Query Variables I have:

```json
{
  "id": "5f945a7b24c84f35ecfae633",
  "withGames": false
}
```

but I get the following error:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Unknown directive \"@include\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 6,
            "column": 11
          }
        ],
        "extensions": {
          "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED",
          "exception": {
            "stacktrace": [
              "GraphQLError: Unknown directive \"@include\".",
              "    at Object.Directive (C:\\Users\\MSI\\projects\\Graphql\\cursobasico\\node_modules\\graphql\\validation\\rules\\KnownDirectivesRule.js:56:29)",
              "    at Object.enter (C:\\Users\\MSI\\projects\\Graphql\\cursobasico\\node_modules\\graphql\\language\\visitor.js:323:29)",
              "    at Object.enter (C:\\Users\\MSI\\projects\\Graphql\\cursobasico\\node_modules\\graphql\\utilities\\TypeInfo.js:370:25)",
              "    at visit (C:\\Users\\MSI\\projects\\Graphql\\cursobasico\\node_modules\\graphql\\language\\visitor.js:243:26)",
              "    at Object.validate (C:\\Users\\MSI\\projects\\Graphql\\cursobasico\\node_modules\\graphql\\validation\\validate.js:69:24)",
              "    at validate (C:\\Users\\MSI\\projects\\Graphql\\cursobasico\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\src\\requestPipeline.ts:510:14)",
              "    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\MSI\\projects\\Graphql\\cursobasico\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\src\\requestPipeline.ts:296:32)",
              "    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
              "    at fulfilled (C:\\Users\\MSI\\projects\\Graphql\\cursobasico\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\dist\\requestPipeline.js:5:58)",
              "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`It was a version problem of the graphql-tools`. Checking the `node_modules/graphql-tools/package.json` file I observed that I was using version 4. I found [here](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/pull/4007) that version 4 had problems with the directives and the use of version 5 was recommended. This is what I did:

```
npm i graphql-tools@5.0.0
```

I restarted the server and refresh the `Playground page` and voila, I already have the `@include` directive and all the others available.